# React Native Stylesheet: what does {flex:1} do?

Tags: flexbox, react-native

React Native uses flexbox for layout. In all of the examples I've seen, they do something like this:

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row'
  }
});
```

I'm curious about the `flex: 1` part. Based on Chris Coyier's definition here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/, `flex: 1` should be the same as `flex-grow: 1`, but to me it looks like `flex: 1` in React Native is equivalent to `display: flex` in CSS.

Here's a CodePen that demonstrates that `flex: 1` the way React Native examples use it doesn't do anything in CSS:

http://codepen.io/johnnyo/pen/BoKbpb

It's not until we use `display: flex` in CSS until flexbox starts to work:

http://codepen.io/johnnyo/pen/epZXgz

So does this mean that `flex: 1` in React Native is equivalent to `display: flex` in CSS?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There is quite a difference between css flexbox and the one implemented by Facebook. Lots of things in common but defaults are very different. Specifically:

```
Everything is display: flex by default. All the behaviors of block and inline-block can be expressed in term of flex but not the opposite.
```

flex: attribute is only used when at the same level there are few components with different flex values (flex: 1, flex: 3) means that the second element should be 3 times bigger than the first one. flex attribute is the only one supported (no grow/shrink support).

More info: https://github.com/facebook/css-layout

Comment: The now link redirects to [github.com/facebook/yoga](https://github.com/facebook/yoga), is it still the same repo?

Comment: When I try decimal numbers between 0 and 1 it seems to work, but is it not recommended?

Answer (score 32):

A remark to Jarek Potiuk's answer: 'flex: 1' does do something in react-native similar to flex-grow behavior. Even if it is the only one with flex: defined.

Styles such as flexDirection, alignItems, justifyContent all define styling of children of the element. Similar to CSS Display: flex, which also defines children.

In contrast, flex: x defines the element itself.

E.g. if a container component has flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'
And there are 3 children:

> child 1 has width 50
>
> child 2 has flex 1 (or any other number, but 1 is common practice)
>
> child 3 has width 50

Then the middle component will 'stretch' so that the 3 children together fill the entire width of the parent component.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation.  That makes sense.  Here's a CodePen that demonstrates your example: http://codepen.io/johnnyo/pen/OyXObB

Answer (score 17):

A lot of tutorials use `flex: 1`, much like as you did in your example. The main reason is because sometimes (depending on the element, such as *ListStyle* by default, if my memory serves) the component will not take up the entire screen/area if you do not define the dimensions, such as the height (eg. `height: '400px'`). *Flex:* is awesome because it keeps things responsive for various sizes.

But I should note that for any component with **no siblings**, the value for flex is totally arbitrary. Ex. for your top-level component, you could say `flex: 43254315` and it does the same thing as `flex: 1`. It just means "take up the entire space" (whatever "entire" that may be).

On the other hand, if you have some **sibling components**, then the flex value matters a lot. For example, if one component is `flex: 2` and another is `flex: 3`, then the first takes up 2/5 of the screen and the second takes up 3/5 of the screen.

In short: Depending on your styles, it might *look* like `flex: 1` is the same as `display: flex`, but that's only because of the way you are using it in your example. You'll see it act very differently if you just give it some siblings.

Answer (score 13):

Like you I struggled to understand this tag that isn't documented properly on Facebook Code, but I eventually discovered that it does two things:

1. Containers consider any children with a `flex` attribute to have a height of 0 for the purpose of determining how much space they take up.
2. Components with `flex: X` expand to take up any room remaining in their container after other components have been laid out. They share this extra space in proportion with their X values.

The first item is why `flex: 1` can appear to have the same effect as `display: flex`. Consider the following JSX code:

```
<ExampleAppContainer>
    <Text>
        I get printed.
    </Text>
    <Text style={{flex: 1}}>
        But I don't :(
    </Text>
</ExampleAppContainer>
```

Only the first text component gets printed, because the second one is considered to have a height of 0. `ExampleAppContainer` allocates enough space for the first text component, and there isn't any room for the second one to expand.

Now consider this code:

```
<ExampleAppContainer style={{flex:1}}>
    <Text>
        I get printed.
    </Text>
    <Text style={{flex: 1}}>
        And so do I!
    </Text>
</ExampleAppContainer>
```

Since `ExampleAppContainer` has `flex: 1`, it expands to take up as much room as it can. Assuming that it is the root component for the React part of your app, this is usually going to be the entire phone screen. Next it allocates sufficient space for the first text component, and allows the second text component to expand, taking up the rest of the screen.

In this fashion you will often need to apply `flex: 1` all the way down you component hierarchy in order to allow your innermost components with `flex: N` room to expand properly.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation but I don't understand how this differs from `flexGrow: 1`, doesn't that also make the element expand to fill all available space?

Answer (score 6):

```
flex: 1
```

1. Tells a component to fill all available space (shared amongst other components with the same parent).
2. If there are sibling components with `flex` values, their parent needs to have `flex: 1` (or higher). If a parent does not have either a fixed width and height or flex, the parent will have dimensions of 0 and the flex children will not be visible.

Comment: 2nd point is more important

Answer (score 3):

this is very simple just think that when you say flex: 1 to any elements that element get all height of parent element if this element have flex: 1 and dont have parent element get all height of screen size.

for example you want have one container element that get all height of screen and this element have three child element that each element have 1/3 height of screen
for this example just get the parent element flex: 1 and three child element flex: 1/3
see code bellow

```
<View style={{flex: 1,backgroundColor: 'red'}}>

        <View style={{flex: 1/3, backgroundColor: 'green'}}></View>

        <View style={{flex: 1/3, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}></View>

        <View style={{flex: 1/3, backgroundColor: 'pink'}}></View>

      </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [React Native documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/height-and-width#flex-dimensions):

> A component can only expand to fill available space if its parent has dimensions greater than `0`. If a parent does not have either a fixed `width` and `height` or `flex`, the parent will have dimensions of `0` and the `flex` children will not be visible.

As such, it is common to set `flex: 1` on the parent of flex items so that the children can expand properly without setting fixed dimensions on the parent.

For example, with the following code, the nested `<View>` will fill all the space under the text, making the background blue. [Try it!](https://snack.expo.dev/AsK5VBZN0)

```
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Text>Some text...</Text>
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue'}} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

However, if `flex: 1` is removed from the parent `View`, then only the text will be shown. [Try it!](https://snack.expo.dev/mQg1Fq4uD)